# Excel does not accept any formula

Tags: excel, search, syntax, formula

I need to write a formula in Excel to look up specific words and write a string into a field depending on them. However, after first tries I realized that every formula I entered is displayed as false. So I even tried the most simple ones as:

```
=SUM(H20, B11)
```

But still, it causes syntax errors. Is something wrong with my Excel? Here is a screenshot of the error that always shows up:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you type in a cell `=1+1`? Also, what language settings is your Excel? Also, are you sure the `,` is the char to separate arguments in each function?

Comment: 1+1 works. The setting are in english, however I also tried ' instead of ". Why is excel not able to give more precise error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it the semicolon was needed instead of ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings in Excel are important, because they affect functions.

Anyways, the easiest way to know what kind of separator you need when using functions in formula, is looking at the little floating help window Excel shows when using a function.

This works in any Excel version. When you type the complete name of a function, Excel shows a little help window explaining how to use the formula:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the semicolon is shown as separator. Depending of how Excel has been set up, this could be a different char, but you could see it in this floating help in any case :)