# Excel if statement replace content with text

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have this excel statement:

```
 =IF(C3="x","Shared","Dedicated")
```

It gives me that standart if = is the first sign then excels takes this as a formula warning.

Where is the mistake in that statement?

Thanks for your help, I tried online search but all pages show my result as working?!?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Found it is it ; not , ...... office 365

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858567/9199828

Answer (score 1):

```
 =IF(C3="x";"Shared";"Dedicated")
```

; not ,